# Barba.js CDN will not load from CDN or node modules?

Tags: javascript, html, css, barbajs

I'm using barba.js in an HTML file right now, and for some reason, it is refusing to load from both CDN and node modules. I've tried using both of the links provided on the installation page of barba.js. I even tried copy and pasting the examples listed on the website, but that didn't work either. PLEASE HELP!!!! HTML linked below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.js"></script>
    
  
    
    
    <title>Home | </title>
</head>

<body data-barba="wrapper">
  <input class="programming_button" type="button" onclick="location.href='programming.html';"/>
  <main class='homepage5' data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="homepage">
    <div class="title_text">
        <h3 class="description">click on a symbol to view.</h3>

        <svg 
        width="300" height="124" viewBox="0 0 300 124" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <mask id="path-1-outside-1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-0.0254974" y="0.495998" width="300" height="124" fill="black">
          <rect fill="white" x="-0.0254974" y="0.495998" width="300" height="124"/>
          <path d="M61.4739 57.576C57.6819 57.576 54.0099 57 50.4579 55.848C46.9539 54.648 44.1939 53.112 42.1779 51.24L44.8419 45.624C46.7619 47.352 49.2099 48.768 52.1859 49.872C55.2099 50.928 58.3059 51.456 61.4739 51.456C65.6499 51.456 68.7699 50.76 70.8339 49.368C72.8979 47.928 73.9299 46.032 73.9299 43.68C73.9299 41.952 73.3539 40.56 72.2019 39.504C71.0979 38.4 69.7059 37.56 68.0259 36.984C66.3939 36.408 64.0659 35.76 61.0419 35.04C57.2499 34.128 54.1779 33.216 51.8259 32.304C49.5219 31.392 47.5299 30 45.8499 28.128C44.2179 26.208 43.4019 23.64 43.4019 20.424C43.4019 17.736 44.0979 15.312 45.4899 13.152C46.9299 10.992 49.0899 9.264 51.9699 7.968C54.8499 6.672 58.4259 6.024 62.6979 6.024C65.6739 6.024 68.6019 6.408 71.4819 7.176C74.3619 7.944 76.8339 9.048 78.8979 10.488L76.5219 16.248C74.4099 14.904 72.1539 13.896 69.7539 13.224C67.3539 12.504 65.0019 12.144 62.6979 12.144C58.6179 12.144 55.5459 12.888 53.4819 14.376C51.4659 15.864 50.4579 17.784 50.4579 20.136C50.4579 21.864 51.0339 23.28 52.1859 24.384C53.3379 25.44 54.7539 26.28 56.4339 26.904C58.1619 27.48 60.4899 28.104 63.4179 28.776C67.2099 29.688 70.2579 30.6 72.5619 31.512C74.8659 32.424 76.8339 33.816 78.4659 35.688C80.1459 37.56 80.9859 40.08 80.9859 43.248C80.9859 45.888 80.2659 48.312 78.8259 50.52C77.3859 52.68 75.2019 54.408 72.2739 55.704C69.3459 56.952 65.7459 57.576 61.4739 57.576Z"/>
          <path d="M86.1767 18.84H93.0887V57H86.1767V18.84ZM89.6327 11.496C88.2887 11.496 87.1607 11.064 86.2487 10.2C85.3847 9.336 84.9527 8.28 84.9527 7.032C84.9527 5.784 85.3847 4.728 86.2487 3.864C87.1607 2.952 88.2887 2.496 89.6327 2.496C90.9767 2.496 92.0807 2.928 92.9447 3.792C93.8567 4.608 94.3127 5.64 94.3127 6.888C94.3127 8.184 93.8567 9.288 92.9447 10.2C92.0807 11.064 90.9767 11.496 89.6327 11.496Z"/>
          <path d="M149.702 18.48C154.502 18.48 158.294 19.872 161.078 22.656C163.91 25.44 165.326 29.568 165.326 35.04V57H158.414V35.832C158.414 32.136 157.55 29.352 155.822 27.48C154.142 25.608 151.718 24.672 148.55 24.672C145.046 24.672 142.262 25.776 140.198 27.984C138.134 30.144 137.102 33.264 137.102 37.344V57H130.19V35.832C130.19 32.136 129.326 29.352 127.598 27.48C125.918 25.608 123.494 24.672 120.326 24.672C116.822 24.672 114.038 25.776 111.974 27.984C109.91 30.144 108.878 33.264 108.878 37.344V57H101.966V18.84H108.59V24.528C109.982 22.56 111.806 21.072 114.062 20.064C116.318 19.008 118.886 18.48 121.766 18.48C124.742 18.48 127.382 19.08 129.686 20.28C131.99 21.48 133.766 23.232 135.014 25.536C136.454 23.328 138.446 21.6 140.99 20.352C143.582 19.104 146.486 18.48 149.702 18.48Z"/>
          <path d="M190.279 57.432C186.487 57.432 183.079 56.592 180.055 54.912C177.031 53.232 174.655 50.928 172.927 48C171.247 45.024 170.407 41.664 170.407 37.92C170.407 34.176 171.247 30.84 172.927 27.912C174.655 24.936 177.031 22.632 180.055 21C183.079 19.32 186.487 18.48 190.279 18.48C194.071 18.48 197.455 19.32 200.431 21C203.455 22.632 205.807 24.936 207.487 27.912C209.215 30.84 210.079 34.176 210.079 37.92C210.079 41.664 209.215 45.024 207.487 48C205.807 50.928 203.455 53.232 200.431 54.912C197.455 56.592 194.071 57.432 190.279 57.432ZM190.279 51.384C192.727 51.384 194.911 50.832 196.831 49.728C198.799 48.576 200.335 46.992 201.439 44.976C202.543 42.912 203.095 40.56 203.095 37.92C203.095 35.28 202.543 32.952 201.439 30.936C200.335 28.872 198.799 27.288 196.831 26.184C194.911 25.08 192.727 24.528 190.279 24.528C187.831 24.528 185.623 25.08 183.655 26.184C181.735 27.288 180.199 28.872 179.047 30.936C177.943 32.952 177.391 35.28 177.391 37.92C177.391 40.56 177.943 42.912 179.047 44.976C180.199 46.992 181.735 48.576 183.655 49.728C185.623 50.832 187.831 51.384 190.279 51.384Z"/>
          <path d="M235.694 18.48C240.542 18.48 244.382 19.896 247.214 22.728C250.094 25.512 251.534 29.616 251.534 35.04V57H244.622V35.832C244.622 32.136 243.734 29.352 241.958 27.48C240.182 25.608 237.638 24.672 234.326 24.672C230.582 24.672 227.63 25.776 225.47 27.984C223.31 30.144 222.23 33.264 222.23 37.344V57H215.318V18.84H221.942V24.6C223.334 22.632 225.206 21.12 227.558 20.064C229.958 19.008 232.67 18.48 235.694 18.48Z"/>
          <path d="M22.2705 121.576C18.4785 121.576 14.8065 121 11.2545 119.848C7.7505 118.648 4.9905 117.112 2.9745 115.24L5.6385 109.624C7.5585 111.352 10.0065 112.768 12.9825 113.872C16.0065 114.928 19.1025 115.456 22.2705 115.456C26.4465 115.456 29.5665 114.76 31.6305 113.368C33.6945 111.928 34.7265 110.032 34.7265 107.68C34.7265 105.952 34.1505 104.56 32.9985 103.504C31.8945 102.4 30.5025 101.56 28.8225 100.984C27.1905 100.408 24.8625 99.76 21.8385 99.04C18.0465 98.128 14.9745 97.216 12.6225 96.304C10.3185 95.392 8.3265 94 6.6465 92.128C5.0145 90.208 4.1985 87.64 4.1985 84.424C4.1985 81.736 4.8945 79.312 6.2865 77.152C7.7265 74.992 9.8865 73.264 12.7665 71.968C15.6465 70.672 19.2225 70.024 23.4945 70.024C26.4705 70.024 29.3985 70.408 32.2785 71.176C35.1585 71.944 37.6305 73.048 39.6945 74.488L37.3185 80.248C35.2065 78.904 32.9505 77.896 30.5505 77.224C28.1505 76.504 25.7985 76.144 23.4945 76.144C19.4145 76.144 16.3425 76.888 14.2785 78.376C12.2625 79.864 11.2545 81.784 11.2545 84.136C11.2545 85.864 11.8305 87.28 12.9825 88.384C14.1345 89.44 15.5505 90.28 17.2305 90.904C18.9585 91.48 21.2865 92.104 24.2145 92.776C28.0065 93.688 31.0545 94.6 33.3585 95.512C35.6625 96.424 37.6305 97.816 39.2625 99.688C40.9425 101.56 41.7825 104.08 41.7825 107.248C41.7825 109.888 41.0625 112.312 39.6225 114.52C38.1825 116.68 35.9985 118.408 33.0705 119.704C30.1425 120.952 26.5425 121.576 22.2705 121.576Z"/>
          <path d="M60.8693 82.48C66.1493 82.48 70.1812 83.776 72.9652 86.368C75.7972 88.96 77.2132 92.824 77.2132 97.96V121H70.6612V115.96C69.5092 117.736 67.8533 119.104 65.6933 120.064C63.5813 120.976 61.0613 121.432 58.1333 121.432C53.8613 121.432 50.4293 120.4 47.8373 118.336C45.2933 116.272 44.0213 113.56 44.0213 110.2C44.0213 106.84 45.2453 104.152 47.6933 102.136C50.1413 100.072 54.0293 99.04 59.3573 99.04H70.3013V97.672C70.3013 94.696 69.4373 92.416 67.7093 90.832C65.9813 89.248 63.4373 88.456 60.0773 88.456C57.8213 88.456 55.6133 88.84 53.4533 89.608C51.2933 90.328 49.4693 91.312 47.9813 92.56L45.1013 87.376C47.0693 85.792 49.4213 84.592 52.1573 83.776C54.8933 82.912 57.7973 82.48 60.8693 82.48ZM59.2853 116.104C61.9253 116.104 64.2053 115.528 66.1253 114.376C68.0453 113.176 69.4373 111.496 70.3013 109.336V104.008H59.6453C53.7893 104.008 50.8613 105.976 50.8613 109.912C50.8613 111.832 51.6053 113.344 53.0933 114.448C54.5813 115.552 56.6453 116.104 59.2853 116.104Z"/>
          <path d="M106.061 82.48C110.909 82.48 114.749 83.896 117.581 86.728C120.461 89.512 121.901 93.616 121.901 99.04V121H114.989V99.832C114.989 96.136 114.101 93.352 112.325 91.48C110.549 89.608 108.004 88.672 104.692 88.672C100.948 88.672 97.9965 89.776 95.8365 91.984C93.6765 94.144 92.5965 97.264 92.5965 101.344V121H85.6845V82.84H92.3085V88.6C93.7005 86.632 95.5725 85.12 97.9245 84.064C100.325 83.008 103.037 82.48 106.061 82.48Z"/>
          <path d="M166.583 67.576V121H159.959V114.952C158.423 117.064 156.479 118.672 154.127 119.776C151.775 120.88 149.183 121.432 146.351 121.432C142.655 121.432 139.343 120.616 136.415 118.984C133.487 117.352 131.183 115.072 129.503 112.144C127.871 109.168 127.055 105.76 127.055 101.92C127.055 98.08 127.871 94.696 129.503 91.768C131.183 88.84 133.487 86.56 136.415 84.928C139.343 83.296 142.655 82.48 146.351 82.48C149.087 82.48 151.607 83.008 153.911 84.064C156.215 85.072 158.135 86.584 159.671 88.6V67.576H166.583ZM146.927 115.384C149.327 115.384 151.511 114.832 153.479 113.728C155.447 112.576 156.983 110.992 158.087 108.976C159.191 106.912 159.743 104.56 159.743 101.92C159.743 99.28 159.191 96.952 158.087 94.936C156.983 92.872 155.447 91.288 153.479 90.184C151.511 89.08 149.327 88.528 146.927 88.528C144.479 88.528 142.271 89.08 140.303 90.184C138.383 91.288 136.847 92.872 135.695 94.936C134.591 96.952 134.039 99.28 134.039 101.92C134.039 104.56 134.591 106.912 135.695 108.976C136.847 110.992 138.383 112.576 140.303 113.728C142.271 114.832 144.479 115.384 146.927 115.384Z"/>
          <path d="M181.965 89.248C183.165 87.04 184.941 85.36 187.293 84.208C189.645 83.056 192.501 82.48 195.861 82.48V89.176C195.477 89.128 194.949 89.104 194.277 89.104C190.533 89.104 187.581 90.232 185.421 92.488C183.309 94.696 182.253 97.864 182.253 101.992V121H175.341V82.84H181.965V89.248Z"/>
          <path d="M234.197 102.136C234.197 102.664 234.149 103.36 234.053 104.224H203.093C203.525 107.584 204.989 110.296 207.485 112.36C210.029 114.376 213.173 115.384 216.917 115.384C221.477 115.384 225.149 113.848 227.933 110.776L231.749 115.24C230.021 117.256 227.861 118.792 225.269 119.848C222.725 120.904 219.869 121.432 216.701 121.432C212.669 121.432 209.093 120.616 205.973 118.984C202.853 117.304 200.429 114.976 198.701 112C197.021 109.024 196.181 105.664 196.181 101.92C196.181 98.224 196.997 94.888 198.629 91.912C200.309 88.936 202.589 86.632 205.469 85C208.397 83.32 211.685 82.48 215.333 82.48C218.981 82.48 222.221 83.32 225.053 85C227.933 86.632 230.165 88.936 231.749 91.912C233.381 94.888 234.197 98.296 234.197 102.136ZM215.333 88.312C212.021 88.312 209.237 89.32 206.981 91.336C204.773 93.352 203.477 95.992 203.093 99.256H227.573C227.189 96.04 225.869 93.424 223.613 91.408C221.405 89.344 218.645 88.312 215.333 88.312Z"/>
          <path d="M296.516 82.84L282.26 121H275.636L264.62 92.056L253.46 121H246.836L232.652 82.84H239.204L250.292 113.224L261.812 82.84H267.644L278.948 113.368L290.324 82.84H296.516Z"/>
          </mask>
          <path d="M61.4739 57.576C57.6819 57.576 54.0099 57 50.4579 55.848C46.9539 54.648 44.1939 53.112 42.1779 51.24L44.8419 45.624C46.7619 47.352 49.2099 48.768 52.1859 49.872C55.2099 50.928 58.3059 51.456 61.4739 51.456C65.6499 51.456 68.7699 50.76 70.8339 49.368C72.8979 47.928 73.9299 46.032 73.9299 43.68C73.9299 41.952 73.3539 40.56 72.2019 39.504C71.0979 38.4 69.7059 37.56 68.0259 36.984C66.3939 36.408 64.0659 35.76 61.0419 35.04C57.2499 34.128 54.1779 33.216 51.8259 32.304C49.5219 31.392 47.5299 30 45.8499 28.128C44.2179 26.208 43.4019 23.64 43.4019 20.424C43.4019 17.736 44.0979 15.312 45.4899 13.152C46.9299 10.992 49.0899 9.264 51.9699 7.968C54.8499 6.672 58.4259 6.024 62.6979 6.024C65.6739 6.024 68.6019 6.408 71.4819 7.176C74.3619 7.944 76.8339 9.048 78.8979 10.488L76.5219 16.248C74.4099 14.904 72.1539 13.896 69.7539 13.224C67.3539 12.504 65.0019 12.144 62.6979 12.144C58.6179 12.144 55.5459 12.888 53.4819 14.376C51.4659 15.864 50.4579 17.784 50.4579 20.136C50.4579 21.864 51.0339 23.28 52.1859 24.384C53.3379 25.44 54.7539 26.28 56.4339 26.904C58.1619 27.48 60.4899 28.104 63.4179 28.776C67.2099 29.688 70.2579 30.6 72.5619 31.512C74.8659 32.424 76.8339 33.816 78.4659 35.688C80.1459 37.56 80.9859 40.08 80.9859 43.248C80.9859 45.888 80.2659 48.312 78.8259 50.52C77.3859 52.68 75.2019 54.408 72.2739 55.704C69.3459 56.952 65.7459 57.576 61.4739 57.576Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M86.1767 18.84H93.0887V57H86.1767V18.84ZM89.6327 11.496C88.2887 11.496 87.1607 11.064 86.2487 10.2C85.3847 9.336 84.9527 8.28 84.9527 7.032C84.9527 5.784 85.3847 4.728 86.2487 3.864C87.1607 2.952 88.2887 2.496 89.6327 2.496C90.9767 2.496 92.0807 2.928 92.9447 3.792C93.8567 4.608 94.3127 5.64 94.3127 6.888C94.3127 8.184 93.8567 9.288 92.9447 10.2C92.0807 11.064 90.9767 11.496 89.6327 11.496Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M149.702 18.48C154.502 18.48 158.294 19.872 161.078 22.656C163.91 25.44 165.326 29.568 165.326 35.04V57H158.414V35.832C158.414 32.136 157.55 29.352 155.822 27.48C154.142 25.608 151.718 24.672 148.55 24.672C145.046 24.672 142.262 25.776 140.198 27.984C138.134 30.144 137.102 33.264 137.102 37.344V57H130.19V35.832C130.19 32.136 129.326 29.352 127.598 27.48C125.918 25.608 123.494 24.672 120.326 24.672C116.822 24.672 114.038 25.776 111.974 27.984C109.91 30.144 108.878 33.264 108.878 37.344V57H101.966V18.84H108.59V24.528C109.982 22.56 111.806 21.072 114.062 20.064C116.318 19.008 118.886 18.48 121.766 18.48C124.742 18.48 127.382 19.08 129.686 20.28C131.99 21.48 133.766 23.232 135.014 25.536C136.454 23.328 138.446 21.6 140.99 20.352C143.582 19.104 146.486 18.48 149.702 18.48Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M190.279 57.432C186.487 57.432 183.079 56.592 180.055 54.912C177.031 53.232 174.655 50.928 172.927 48C171.247 45.024 170.407 41.664 170.407 37.92C170.407 34.176 171.247 30.84 172.927 27.912C174.655 24.936 177.031 22.632 180.055 21C183.079 19.32 186.487 18.48 190.279 18.48C194.071 18.48 197.455 19.32 200.431 21C203.455 22.632 205.807 24.936 207.487 27.912C209.215 30.84 210.079 34.176 210.079 37.92C210.079 41.664 209.215 45.024 207.487 48C205.807 50.928 203.455 53.232 200.431 54.912C197.455 56.592 194.071 57.432 190.279 57.432ZM190.279 51.384C192.727 51.384 194.911 50.832 196.831 49.728C198.799 48.576 200.335 46.992 201.439 44.976C202.543 42.912 203.095 40.56 203.095 37.92C203.095 35.28 202.543 32.952 201.439 30.936C200.335 28.872 198.799 27.288 196.831 26.184C194.911 25.08 192.727 24.528 190.279 24.528C187.831 24.528 185.623 25.08 183.655 26.184C181.735 27.288 180.199 28.872 179.047 30.936C177.943 32.952 177.391 35.28 177.391 37.92C177.391 40.56 177.943 42.912 179.047 44.976C180.199 46.992 181.735 48.576 183.655 49.728C185.623 50.832 187.831 51.384 190.279 51.384Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M235.694 18.48C240.542 18.48 244.382 19.896 247.214 22.728C250.094 25.512 251.534 29.616 251.534 35.04V57H244.622V35.832C244.622 32.136 243.734 29.352 241.958 27.48C240.182 25.608 237.638 24.672 234.326 24.672C230.582 24.672 227.63 25.776 225.47 27.984C223.31 30.144 222.23 33.264 222.23 37.344V57H215.318V18.84H221.942V24.6C223.334 22.632 225.206 21.12 227.558 20.064C229.958 19.008 232.67 18.48 235.694 18.48Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M22.2705 121.576C18.4785 121.576 14.8065 121 11.2545 119.848C7.7505 118.648 4.9905 117.112 2.9745 115.24L5.6385 109.624C7.5585 111.352 10.0065 112.768 12.9825 113.872C16.0065 114.928 19.1025 115.456 22.2705 115.456C26.4465 115.456 29.5665 114.76 31.6305 113.368C33.6945 111.928 34.7265 110.032 34.7265 107.68C34.7265 105.952 34.1505 104.56 32.9985 103.504C31.8945 102.4 30.5025 101.56 28.8225 100.984C27.1905 100.408 24.8625 99.76 21.8385 99.04C18.0465 98.128 14.9745 97.216 12.6225 96.304C10.3185 95.392 8.3265 94 6.6465 92.128C5.0145 90.208 4.1985 87.64 4.1985 84.424C4.1985 81.736 4.8945 79.312 6.2865 77.152C7.7265 74.992 9.8865 73.264 12.7665 71.968C15.6465 70.672 19.2225 70.024 23.4945 70.024C26.4705 70.024 29.3985 70.408 32.2785 71.176C35.1585 71.944 37.6305 73.048 39.6945 74.488L37.3185 80.248C35.2065 78.904 32.9505 77.896 30.5505 77.224C28.1505 76.504 25.7985 76.144 23.4945 76.144C19.4145 76.144 16.3425 76.888 14.2785 78.376C12.2625 79.864 11.2545 81.784 11.2545 84.136C11.2545 85.864 11.8305 87.28 12.9825 88.384C14.1345 89.44 15.5505 90.28 17.2305 90.904C18.9585 91.48 21.2865 92.104 24.2145 92.776C28.0065 93.688 31.0545 94.6 33.3585 95.512C35.6625 96.424 37.6305 97.816 39.2625 99.688C40.9425 101.56 41.7825 104.08 41.7825 107.248C41.7825 109.888 41.0625 112.312 39.6225 114.52C38.1825 116.68 35.9985 118.408 33.0705 119.704C30.1425 120.952 26.5425 121.576 22.2705 121.576Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M60.8693 82.48C66.1493 82.48 70.1812 83.776 72.9652 86.368C75.7972 88.96 77.2132 92.824 77.2132 97.96V121H70.6612V115.96C69.5092 117.736 67.8533 119.104 65.6933 120.064C63.5813 120.976 61.0613 121.432 58.1333 121.432C53.8613 121.432 50.4293 120.4 47.8373 118.336C45.2933 116.272 44.0213 113.56 44.0213 110.2C44.0213 106.84 45.2453 104.152 47.6933 102.136C50.1413 100.072 54.0293 99.04 59.3573 99.04H70.3013V97.672C70.3013 94.696 69.4373 92.416 67.7093 90.832C65.9813 89.248 63.4373 88.456 60.0773 88.456C57.8213 88.456 55.6133 88.84 53.4533 89.608C51.2933 90.328 49.4693 91.312 47.9813 92.56L45.1013 87.376C47.0693 85.792 49.4213 84.592 52.1573 83.776C54.8933 82.912 57.7973 82.48 60.8693 82.48ZM59.2853 116.104C61.9253 116.104 64.2053 115.528 66.1253 114.376C68.0453 113.176 69.4373 111.496 70.3013 109.336V104.008H59.6453C53.7893 104.008 50.8613 105.976 50.8613 109.912C50.8613 111.832 51.6053 113.344 53.0933 114.448C54.5813 115.552 56.6453 116.104 59.2853 116.104Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M106.061 82.48C110.909 82.48 114.749 83.896 117.581 86.728C120.461 89.512 121.901 93.616 121.901 99.04V121H114.989V99.832C114.989 96.136 114.101 93.352 112.325 91.48C110.549 89.608 108.004 88.672 104.692 88.672C100.948 88.672 97.9965 89.776 95.8365 91.984C93.6765 94.144 92.5965 97.264 92.5965 101.344V121H85.6845V82.84H92.3085V88.6C93.7005 86.632 95.5725 85.12 97.9245 84.064C100.325 83.008 103.037 82.48 106.061 82.48Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M166.583 67.576V121H159.959V114.952C158.423 117.064 156.479 118.672 154.127 119.776C151.775 120.88 149.183 121.432 146.351 121.432C142.655 121.432 139.343 120.616 136.415 118.984C133.487 117.352 131.183 115.072 129.503 112.144C127.871 109.168 127.055 105.76 127.055 101.92C127.055 98.08 127.871 94.696 129.503 91.768C131.183 88.84 133.487 86.56 136.415 84.928C139.343 83.296 142.655 82.48 146.351 82.48C149.087 82.48 151.607 83.008 153.911 84.064C156.215 85.072 158.135 86.584 159.671 88.6V67.576H166.583ZM146.927 115.384C149.327 115.384 151.511 114.832 153.479 113.728C155.447 112.576 156.983 110.992 158.087 108.976C159.191 106.912 159.743 104.56 159.743 101.92C159.743 99.28 159.191 96.952 158.087 94.936C156.983 92.872 155.447 91.288 153.479 90.184C151.511 89.08 149.327 88.528 146.927 88.528C144.479 88.528 142.271 89.08 140.303 90.184C138.383 91.288 136.847 92.872 135.695 94.936C134.591 96.952 134.039 99.28 134.039 101.92C134.039 104.56 134.591 106.912 135.695 108.976C136.847 110.992 138.383 112.576 140.303 113.728C142.271 114.832 144.479 115.384 146.927 115.384Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M181.965 89.248C183.165 87.04 184.941 85.36 187.293 84.208C189.645 83.056 192.501 82.48 195.861 82.48V89.176C195.477 89.128 194.949 89.104 194.277 89.104C190.533 89.104 187.581 90.232 185.421 92.488C183.309 94.696 182.253 97.864 182.253 101.992V121H175.341V82.84H181.965V89.248Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M234.197 102.136C234.197 102.664 234.149 103.36 234.053 104.224H203.093C203.525 107.584 204.989 110.296 207.485 112.36C210.029 114.376 213.173 115.384 216.917 115.384C221.477 115.384 225.149 113.848 227.933 110.776L231.749 115.24C230.021 117.256 227.861 118.792 225.269 119.848C222.725 120.904 219.869 121.432 216.701 121.432C212.669 121.432 209.093 120.616 205.973 118.984C202.853 117.304 200.429 114.976 198.701 112C197.021 109.024 196.181 105.664 196.181 101.92C196.181 98.224 196.997 94.888 198.629 91.912C200.309 88.936 202.589 86.632 205.469 85C208.397 83.32 211.685 82.48 215.333 82.48C218.981 82.48 222.221 83.32 225.053 85C227.933 86.632 230.165 88.936 231.749 91.912C233.381 94.888 234.197 98.296 234.197 102.136ZM215.333 88.312C212.021 88.312 209.237 89.32 206.981 91.336C204.773 93.352 203.477 95.992 203.093 99.256H227.573C227.189 96.04 225.869 93.424 223.613 91.408C221.405 89.344 218.645 88.312 215.333 88.312Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
          <path d="M296.516 82.84L282.26 121H275.636L264.62 92.056L253.46 121H246.836L232.652 82.84H239.204L250.292 113.224L261.812 82.84H267.644L278.948 113.368L290.324 82.84H296.516Z" stroke="#F0F0C9" stroke-width="4" mask="url(#path-1-outside-1)"/>
        </svg>
    </div>


    <div class="models3d">
      <script src="./node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
      <script type='module' src="index.js"></script>
    </div>

   

    <div class="transition_background"></div>
   
  </main>
  
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
  <script>
  barba.init({
    transitions: [{
      name: 'homepage',
      leave() {
      anime({
        targets: '.transition_background',
        backgroundColor:'blue',
        delay: 2800,
        duration:1500
        
        
        });
  
      
      },
      enter() {
        anime({
        targets: '.transition_background',
        backgroundColor:'blue',
        delay: 2800,
        duration:1500
        
        
        });
      }
    }]
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: is there some sort of error in the browser developer tools console? the link looks fine, so it should load

Comment: @jaromandaX The developer console says this `DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://unpkg.com/@barba/barba.umd.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

Comment: failure to load a source map doesn't stop **correctly** written code from running - when putting your code in a browser, I get an error about module not defined in `anime.js` - now that's an error that would prevent the code from executing correctly - but you  don't have that error - can't help you

Comment: @jaromandaX I actually do get that error, but when I remove anime it still does not work unfortunately

Comment: anime.js fails to load, then not loading anime.js won't change the issue you are having, of course, the problem is that your code probably relies on anime.js, and it isn't loading